# How to detect incorrect kwarg names in python

Tags: python, pandas, deprecated

I just discovered that the kwarg `skip_footer` for the function `pandas.read_excel()` was deprecated in version 0.23.0, and is now called `skipfooter`.  It appears that `skip_footer` is silently ignored, making it rather more difficult figure out why my code stopped working as it should.

Edit:

> Ok, I lied: I was actually using pandas.ExcelFile.parse(). The documentation suggests they take the same arguments, but in the source code there appear to be some small differences--including with this parameter. I am not suppressing or ignoring warnings (to the best of my knowledge)

Is there a way to get a warning or exception to alert me when I use an incorrect kwarg?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `pandas.ExcelFile.parse()` source code, it does *not* check for `skip_footer` in `**kwds`, and neither do the underlying methods and functions it uses.

So it will indeed silently ignore most unknown keywords.

While Python complains about missing positional parameters, it *cannot* check keyword arguments. AFAIK, there is no mechanism *built into the language* to allow for that.

Individual functions *can* be written to reject invalid keywords:

```
def kwtest(**kwds):
     allowed = {'spam', 'eggs', 'cheese'}
     invalid = set(kwds.keys()) - allowed
     if invalid:
         raise ValueError(f'invalid keyword arguments {invalid}')
```

---

(old answer)

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and the [code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a272b60aabc2a3b4128a7365e9b2b0080bcd5121/pandas/io/excel/_base.py) for Pandas, the `skip_footer` keyword argument *is still there*.

However, the `read_excel` function is marked with a `@deprecate_kwarg` decorator for `skip_footer`. As far as I can tell, using the `skip_footer` keyword argument *should* raise a `FutureWarning` exception.

Are you perhaps suppressing or ignoring warnings?

Comment: Ok, I lied:  I was actually using `pandas.ExcelFile.parse()`.  The documentation suggests they take the same arguments, but in the source code there appear to be some small differences--including with this parameter. I am not suppressing or ignoring warnings (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: So does this mean it is 100% impossible for me to be alerted when I use a deprecated or even misspelled keyword?

Comment: @adr The only way for you to be alerted is if the function in question *explicitly* tests all keyword arguments and raises an exception when invalid keyword arguments are found.